# 11. Given a file, replace all occurrence of word “DEF” with “ABC” from 5th line till end in only those lines that contains word “MNO”

Tags: shell-script, sed

```sh
#!/bin/sh

counter=5
string="MNO"
while [ $counter -gt 0 ]
do
        for item in /Users/kristinautas/Desktop/DEFABC.txt
        do
                if [[ $(gsed $counter DEFABC.txt)=*string* ]]; then
                        gsed -i "$counter s/DEF/ABC/g" "DEFABC.txt"
                        counter=$(($counter+1))
                fi
        done
done
```

I was able to substitute all occurrences of "DEF" string with "ABC" string starting from line 5 in my file called "DEFABC.txt". However, when I try to add another condition with an if statement (only substitute if the line contains "MNO" string) the script still substitutes all occurrences after line 5. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

sed can do this on its own:

```
sed -e '5,${/MNO/s/DEF/ABC/g;}'
```

This:

1. Selects only lines from 5 to the end to act on, with the code in the braces.
2. Then further selects only those lines from that set containing `MNO`, to act on with the `s`ubstitution command to replace `DEF` with `ABC` on those lines.

All other lines are printed unchanged.

Comment: Thank you! This command just prints the output to the console but does nothing to a file. How do I actually substitute the values in a file?

Comment: @Kristina use `-i` instead of `-e`.

Comment: Works fine, thank you!

Comment: @Kristina Good! If this solves your issue, please consider ["accepting" the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is the best way to show gratitude on this site.  Accepting an answer not only marks the question as resolved, but also signals to _future readers_ that the accepted answer actually solved the issue.  More information about this is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

Try the below command

```
sed –n '10,$p' file1|sed '/MNO/s/ABC/DEF/'
```

Comment: This fails in replacing the words on lines 5 through to 9, and it fails to write the changes back to the original file (which the OP's code appears to want to do).